# Global Array Issues Not Updating, C Programming

Tags: c, arrays, global-variables, global

I have a program distributed across a number of files. There are a number of functions which need access to a global array. The issue I'm having is that I don't know the size of the array before the program starts. It opens up a file and then downloads a number of points, and then the array is created with a corresponding size. But for the array to be global, it needs to be declared outside of the main function i.e. before I know the number of points.

What I've tried to do right now is:

file1.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file3.h"
int useful[];
int main()
{
    int useful[10];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        useful[i] = i+1;
    }

    SPN();

    return 0;
}
```

file2.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file3.h"

void SPN() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%i\n", useful[i]);
    }
}
```

file3.h:

```
extern int useful[];
extern void SPN();
```

What I'm getting in output is just a bunch of 0s. At first I was thinking that the second int useful[... in file1.c creates a new array with a different internal name, but that doesn't seem to make any sense considering that no segmentation fault is triggered by SPN() when it tries to access memory outside the arrays bounds (if useful[] creates an array and isn't changed, it has default size 1 i.e. < 10). Help?

Comment: What is the *size* of `useful`? C doesn't have any kind of dynamic arrays.

Comment: "I have a program distributed across a number of files" Please simplify to a [mcve].

Comment: Also, the definition of `int useful[10];` inside the `main` function defines a *second* and *different* variable, that shadows the global variable and is only usable inside the `main` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `int useful[10];` isn't initializing the global `int useful[];` or anything like that. It's a new variable, and with the loop here

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    useful[i] = i+1;
}
```

You're modifying the second `useful` without touching the global one. This is then discarded at the end of the function.

Instead have a global variable like this:

```
int *useful;
```

And initialize it this way:

```
useful = malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
```

Answer (score 2):

The declaration of `useful` inside the `main` is **shadowing** the external one.
This means  that the values that you think are inserting (in the `main`) in the global variable  are actually going into the local variable.

[Take a look at the following article about shadowing for more info.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

It might also be interesting to look at [scope rules in C.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope)